# If two cells contains certain text put the text value of the adjacent cell into a new cell

Tags: excel

I wanted to ask how in Excel can I match a text value in two columns and if there is a match, then copy/paste the value of an adjacent cell into a new cell.

For example:

```
   A         B       C                  L         M
gene_id     gene    value     ...    gene_id     gene
XLOC001     top     20               XLOC003      ?
XLOC002     high    5                XLOC001      ?
XLOC003     left    45               XLOC002      ?
XLOC004     right   10               XLOC004      ?
```

The formula in column M will look in the first row in column L and find a match in column A. If there is a match then return the value in column B. I can then copy/paste this formula for the other rows in column M.

The output will be:

```
   A         B       C                  L         M
gene_id     gene    value     ...    gene_id     gene
XLOC001     top     20               XLOC003     left
XLOC002     high    5                XLOC001     top 
XLOC003     left    45               XLOC002     high
XLOC004     right   10               XLOC004     right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to display the default message of "N/A" if the value was not found. The dollar signs in the range reference makes sure that the range stays the same when you copy and paste the formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(L2, $A$2:$B$5, 2, FALSE)
```

Use this to display a message of "Not Found" if the value was not found:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L2, $A$2:$B$5, 2, FALSE), "Not Found")
```

or just to leave the cell blank:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L2, $A$2:$B$5, 2, FALSE), "")
```

(Simplified previous code, credit goes to chancea.)

Comment: You could simplify that to `IFERROR(...,"Not Found")` and `IFERROR(...,"")`

Comment: Thanks @chancea! I learn something new everyday. I have updated my code to your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case for the `Vlookup()` formula.

```
=VLookup(L2, A2:B5, 2, False)
```

Put that in M2 and you will have your answer.

`L2` here is the value we are looking up. `A2:B5` is the range we are looking in (the first column in the range is the one that is searched). `2` tells it which column from that range it should pull the results. `False` is almost always `false` so no need to worry about that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup might be the function you're after. A vlookup looks for a value in the leftmost column of a table and then returns a value from the row that the searched for value is found (how far along that row is determined by you).

The vlookup formula consists of 4 parts:

1.SearchFor this is the value that is being searched for. In your example it would be L2.

2.WhereToSearch this is the range in which to search and in which the answer lives. In your example this would be A2:B5.

3.WhichColumn this is the column in the WhereToSearch range which has the answer in it. In your example this would be 2

4.NearOrExact you decide whether the vlookup should search for a close value or an exact value. In your example this would be False.

Structure of the vlookup formula:

=vlookup ( SearchFor , WhereToSearch , WhichColumn , NearOrExact )

Source: [www.excelvlookuphelp.com](http://www.excelvlookuphelp.com)